# Is c# ref int foo implemented as C++ int **foo?

Tags: c#, .net

I was talking with a coworker about this yesterday and it got me thinking about .Net's pass by reference.

```
// C#
class Foo {}

static void Test(ref Foo foo) { ... };
static void Main()
{ 
    Foo f;
    Test(ref foo);
}
```

Has to be implemented with a double indirection because we're changing the value of the pointer. Because all reference types are references (pointers)

```
// C#
static void Test(Foo foo) { ... }
static void Test(ref Foo foo) { ... };
```

equates to something like

```
// C++
void Test(Foo *foo);
void Test(Foo **foo);
```

But if this is a **VALUE** type, we don't actually need the double indirection. So I'm curious if

```
// C#
static void Test(ref int bar) { ... }
```

becomes

```
// C++
void Test(int *bar);
// or
void Test(int **bar);
```

1/29/10 Update:
Reading all the answers, I realize that I was not exactly clear enough in what I wanted and I was misleading by throwing in C++ to what was going on. What I was primarily interested in was how it was implemented in the CLR and what the JIT would do to produce assembly for it. Thanks for all the answers, I found them all to be correct from a perspective but I chose the one that was closest to the question I *thought* I had asked.

Comment: See Jon Skeets article on parameter passing http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: "But if this is a reference type, we don't actually need the double indirection." - that may or may not be true depending on what is desired.  There are times when a `ref` parameter to a reference type is useful.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, when want to update the reference and not the object itself.

Comment: You meant to say "if this is a *value* type we don't actually need the double indirection", right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion all, Eric you're absolutely right I meant VALUE instead of REFERENCE. A very unfortunate mistype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, when you have a method

```
void M(ref int f) { }
```

and you call it

```
int x = 123;
M(ref int x):
```

how does this work?

*Logically*, this means "x and f refer to the same storage location".

The way we actually implement that *in the CLR* is f is of type "managed reference to variable that can contain an integer".  We pass the managed address of local variable x to M.

The analog of that in C++ would be a method that takes an &int -- a reference to a variable that can contain an int.

Is that clear?

Answer (score 6):

The right way to think of `ref` is an alias for a storage location. Thus, when you say

```
int x;
Foo(ref x);
```

and `Foo` is declared as

```
void Foo(ref int y)
```

you are to think of `x` and `y` as aliases for the same location in the method call above.

So, `void Foo(ref int y)` in C# is analogous with `void Foo(int &y)` in C++.

Comment: I understand this perspective as the appropriate context to consider the CLR in the abstract divorced from an actual implementation. Perhaps I mislead people when I asked about what happened in C++. I'm more interested in what the JIT will produce in assembly. Even in C++, references (&y in your sample) are implemented with pointers. I was only using C++ because I mistakenly believed it was sufficiently expressive and low-level and many people would be familiar with it.

Answer (score 5):

A reference is not a pointer.

---

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

This declares a "memory cell" which holds a reference to an instance of Foo. Then it initializes a new instance of `Foo` and stores the reference in the memory cell.

```
Bar(Foo x) { x = new Foo(); }
```

This declares method with a `Foo` parameter, which is essentially a local variable (like foo) which happens to be assigned automatically when the method is invoked with an argument.

The statement in the method creates a new instance of `Foo` and stores the reference to the instance in memory cell `x`. Memory cell `foo` remains unchanged.

```
Bar(foo);
```

This invokes `Bar` by copying the value stored in memory cell `foo` to memory cell `x` -- **call by value**.

Exactly the same happens if you write `int` instead of `Foo`, except that the value stored in the memory cells is not a reference but the actual value.

---

```
Qux(ref Foo y) { y = new Foo(); }
```

This declares a method with a `Foo&` parameter, which is essentially a local variable that contains the address of a memory cell which holds a reference to an object of type `Foo`.

```
Qux(ref x);
```

This invokes `Qux` by setting `y` to the address of memory cell `x` -- **call by reference**.

The statement in `Qux` creates a new instance of `Foo` and stores the reference to the object in the memory cell which is located at address `y` (which is the address of  `foo`). So `foo` is assigned the reference to the new instance and changes.

Exactly the same happens when `Foo` is an `int`, except that the value stored in the memory cell passed by reference is not a reference to an object but the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is & not * you are confusing it with a pointer. So this would mean that it will be passed as:

```
void Test(Foo &bar);
```

Comment: Which, at the ABI level, is the same thing: pass the address of bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a value type like int would use only a single level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

1. `MyClass` --> `MyClass*` (or, actually, `shared_ptr<MyClass>`)
2. `ref` --> `&`

C#:

```
void doSomething(int myInt);
void doSomethingElse(ref int myIntRef);
void doSomething(Foo foo);
void doSomethingElse(ref Foo fooRef);
```

C++:

```
void doSomething(int myInt);
void doSomethingElse(int& myInt);
void doSomething(Foo* fooPtr);
void doSomething(Foo*& fooPtrRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check how it is implemented in C++/CLI. I found good explanation in a book: [Expert C++/CLI: NET for Visual C++ programmers](http://books.google.com/books?id=wZoQyVi5f60C), page 83.

`Foo^` is defined as "managed pointer to Foo", equivalent to `UnmanagedFoo*`.

`int%` and `Foo^%` are "managed references" and they are equivalent to `int&` and `UnmanagedFoo*&`.